# swift syntax using var ={}() meaning?

Tags: swift, syntax, properties

I'm new to Swift sorry if this might seem too simple. But I could not find answer from anywhere.

I am trying to understand this syntax below. The code have `=` then `{..}()` why need `()` at the end and also `=` sign for ?

```
var productLines: [ProductLine] = { return ProductLine.productLines() }()
```

I understand that computed variable would be something like .. this below

```
var varA: [arrayOutput] { return someArray }
```

what exactly is `={ return something }()`  called or mean in swift ?

Comment: `{ ... }` is a closure (an inline function definition). `()` calls that function`.

Comment: What this does, is setting the variable `productLines` initially with the result of the closure `{ return ProductLine.productLines() }` The `()` calls that closure function. So the value of `productLines` can be overwritten later. So no, this is not a computed property.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#SECdefineandcall

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see there is a closure for setting the initial value of the variable. A closure can be described as an anonymous code block.

This is what your code looks like:

```
var productLines: [ProductLine] = { return ProductLine.productLines() }()
```

Let me expand your code like this:

```
var productLines: [ProductLine] = { () -> [ProductLine] in 
    return ProductLine.productLines() 
}()
```

The closure itself consists of the following code

```
{ () -> [ProductLine] in 
    return ProductLine.productLines() 
}
```

The two round brackets `()` are used to execute the closure.
So what you see is not a computed property. You are therefore able to change the value of `productLines` like this afterwards:

```
productLines = [ProductLine]()
```

If it was a computed property instead, you would get an error like this one:

> Cannot assign to property: productLines is a get-only property

Comment: Thank you so much This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Excellent answer. (Voted). I was gearing up to write an explanation, but you covered all the bases.